# Attaching Metadata in Clojure

Tags: clojure

I understand how to attach metadata such as:

```
(def x ^{:foo true} [1 2])
```

But a Clojure video on Youtube uses the example:

```
(def ^{:foo true} x [1 2])
```

(meta) doesn't return the metadata on the Youtube example.

What is it attaching the metadata to, why would you do this and how do I return the metadata? Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

`^` is a [reader macro](http://clojure.org/reader) that "first reads the metadata and attaches it to the next form"

Attach metadata to the vector `[1 2]`

```
(def x ^{:foo true} [1 2])
(meta x) ;; x resolves to the vector, `meta` retrieves the metadata attached to it
```

Attach metadata to the var `x`

```
(def ^{:foo true} x [1 2])
(meta #'x) ;; retrieve the metadata from the var `x`
```

Consider this repl session where we attach metadata to the var and the value:

```
user=> (def ^{:var-foo true} x ^{:val-foo true} [1 2])
#'user/x
user=> (meta x)
{:val-foo true}
user=> (meta #'x)
{:ns #<Namespace user>, :name x, :file "NO_SOURCE_PATH", :var-foo true, :column 1, :line 1}
```